# My Preview shows old Input and new Input how can i show only new Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5

When i Input 2 Images to Preview without Upload, it shows them just fine. The Problem comes when i pick other Files. They are added into the Preview instead of getting deleted. Basically now only the new 2 Images would be Uploaded but in the Preview he sees 4 Images. How can i delete the old Images when he Input new ones.

I figured a If Statement would help the Case but i am not sure how to write it.

This is my JS Preview:

```
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if ('.previewdeleter' ===('image') ){
            var deletepreview = ('previewdeleter')
        }

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $('<div class="previewdeleter position-relative" data-item-id-div="input.files[i].length" style="height:200px;width: 200px; display: inline-block; position: relative !important;">' +
                        '<img alt="" src=' + event.target.result + ' style="height:200px;width: 100%; display: inline-block;">')
                        .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i],);
            }

        }


    };

    $('#images').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, '#previewHolder',);
    });

});
```

This is my HTML:

```
               <input value="" type="file" id="images" name="images[]" accept="image/*" multiple />
                <div id="previewHolder" data-item-id-div="input.files[i].length" multiple="" class="previewdeleter position-relative">
                </div>
```

Comment: what is with the random `()` around your strings?

Comment: Empty placeToInsertImagePreview before you loop?

Comment: @epascarello I just had it as an Example there. I wasn't sure how to fix that properly but yeah i came to the same Conclusion after some Time. Just dumb of me, wanting to find a Solution with an If Statement while it was waaaay simpler

Comment: Issue with if statement is you would than have to keep track of the items that were removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using .appendTo - the image preview will be added to the image preview element. This means that everytime you choose a image the preview will show extra images.

To prevent this you should empty the preview box before adding the new previews, that can be achieved like this:

```
$('#previewHolder').empty();
```

With original code it would work like this:

```
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
        $('#previewHolder').empty(); // Empty previewholder

        if ('.previewdeleter' ===('image') ){
            var deletepreview = ('previewdeleter')
        }

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $('<div class="previewdeleter position-relative" data-item-id-div="input.files[i].length" style="height:200px;width: 200px; display: inline-block; position: relative !important;">' +
                        '<img alt="" src=' + event.target.result + ' style="height:200px;width: 100%; display: inline-block;">')
                        .appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i],);
            }

        }


    };

    $('#images').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, '#previewHolder',);
});

});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I tried to do a If Statement first but then i came to this Solution as well. Thank you for your help

Comment: Anytime, no problem ;)